# Entity framework code first class relationships

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I am trying to create my model in Entity Framework and I am trying to go about it using code first option.

I currently have 3 tables in my database.  My status table has all statuses used across the web application.  I have a news table.  And I have a news status table.  The reason why I did it like this is because I don't want all the statuses available to the news items, just a couple of them.  So my 3 tables will look like this:

News Table:

```
NewsId int required primary key
Title varchar required
Body varchar required
NewsStatusId int required foreign key
```

NewStatus Table:

```
NewsStatusId int required primary key
StatusId int required foreign key
```

Status Table

```
StatusId int required primary key
Name varchar required
```

When creating the classes for this, do I need to creates classes for News, Status and NewsStatus?  I was thinking just for News and Status?  What would my relationships look like between the 2/3 classes?

My News class looks like this

```
public class News
{
     public int NewsId { get; set; }
     // rest of my properties
     public int StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

Status class:

```
public class Status
{
     public int StatusId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What would these classes look like with relationships between the 2/3 classes?

Any code samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need any fluent API for a basic Many-to-Many association between News and Status. Everything will be inferred by Code First base on conventions. That said, we can customize your DB schema with fluent API based on your requirements.

```
public class News
{
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<News> Newses { get; set; }
}

public class Ctp5Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<News> Newses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that in a Many to Many association like this, there is not going to be a `NewsStatusId` as a foreign key on News class, instead, a NewsId foreign key will be show up on the link table that references the PK on News table. If you really need to have a `NewsStatusId` on News class, then we have to break this association to 2 one-to-many association which means we end up having 3 entities and not 2.

Comment: Thanks. Do I still need the NewsStatus table? I don't know how the linking is done from the NewsStatus table to the Status and News tables? Or am I getting it all wrong here? How would the table structure then look like?

Comment: Yes, you need it but it will be automatically created and managed by EF. Your logical model does not have an Entity like NewsStatus. The join table in a Many to Many relationship will contain *only* foreign keys from the relationship ends (i.e. Status and News tables) or you have to break it down to 2 one to many association hence introducing a new Entity like NewsStatus to hold the foreign keys as well as any other required properties. The code I showed in my answer goes with the first way. Let me know if you need to do it in the second way and I'll show you how it is done.

Comment: In my object model, what is the relationship then between News and Status? 1 to M?  Have you got some code on how to fully implement this? I have not yet used EF's code first assemblies, are there any decent tutorials.  Even Craig's code sample below is new to me.

Comment: If by `object model` you mean your tables definitions then there is no relationship between News and Status, instead News has a many to one relationship with NewStatus and Status has a one to many relationship with NewStatus. Again there is no direct association/relationships between News and Status. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, is it a legacy database that you are trying to model with code first?

Comment: Regarding your second question, there are not much resources on EF Code First yet, there are very few blog posts that you can find on ADO.Net team blog. I've started some EF Code First articles on my blog as well that you might find them useful :)

Comment: No I am designing a new system.  So I am trying to create the model from the 3 tables above.  I've read that when designing your model you should not think in an relational way, but in an object way.

Comment: So then you need to decide if you want your join table to hold attributes other than PKs of the two table, if so, then you have to break your *:* association down to two 1:* association.

Answer (score 1):

Just `News` and `Status`. You'd write something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<News>()
    .HasMany(n => n.Statuses) 
    .WithMany(s => s.News);
```

(Adjust pluralizations to your liking.)

Comment: What is modelBuilder and where would I put it? See my updated post. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand how this code is going to link up my 3 tables?  Have you got some more code for me or links to go and read up on your code?